# Oracle: Missing Expression

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this set of code, it didn't return error when I compiled it.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PARAM_CHECK
(
  PARAM_CODE IN VARCHAR2, 
  TABLE_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
  ISEXIST OUT INTEGER
) 
IS 
SQLSTMT VARCHAR2(200);
V_COUNT NUMBER;
BEGIN  
SQLSTMT := 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO '|| V_COUNT ||' FROM '|| TABLE_NAME ||' WHERE ID = '''||PARAM_CODE||''' AND ROWNUM = 1';  
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLSTMT;
COMMIT;
IF 
V_COUNT = 0 THEN
ISEXIST := 0;
ELSE
ISEXIST := 1;
END IF;

END PARAM_CHECK;
```

But when after I try to run the procedure, it return this error:

```
Connecting to the database SAA.
ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06512: at "SAA.PARAM_CHECK", line 12
ORA-06512: at line 9
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database SAA.
```

I have no idea why it return this error, plus when I compile everything is okay. I did search for the specific ORA error but didn't help much. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you are executing the sql dynamically, and your select statement  has a syntax error.  Print out the sqlstmt value and run it in a sql client to see the error.  Also, when you fix the syntax, the select will still not work. The execute immedidate know nothing about the v_count variable.   [Here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm) are some examples.  Avoid using string literal parameters and bind them instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vcount is uninitialised at the time of the inclusion of its value into the sql statement so it produces a sytactically wrong blank at this position.

If it was feasible at all you'd have to write

```
SQLSTMT := 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM '|| TABLE_NAME ||' WHERE ID = '''||PARAM_CODE||''' AND ROWNUM = 1';
```

but this won't work either iirc since execute immediate opens a new scope.

You have to resort to

```
SQLSTMT := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '|| TABLE_NAME ||' WHERE ID = '''||PARAM_CODE||''' AND ROWNUM = 1';
EXecute immediate sqlstmt into v_count;
```

Comment: dear collapsar,

I tried your solution and yes as per your expectation, it return another error:

`Connecting to the database SAA.`
`ORA-00905: missing keyword`
`ORA-06512: at "SAA.PARAM_CHECK", line 12`
`ORA-06512: at line 9`
`Process exited.`
`Disconnecting from the database SAA.`

Comment: thanks man, I just read your updated answer and it works! So, as per commented by OldProgrammer above, execute immedidate know nothing about the v_count variable. I will keep in mind. Thanks for the helps :)